# how to enable __BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD in stdlib.h

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

I am now trying to build a c++ library in linux with cmake. If I do not enable -std=c++0x option, I always get compilation errors  `error: 'div_t' was not declared in this scope` for the following codes:

```
        int xPos;
        div_t divResult;
        divResult = div(xPos,8);
```

Then if I enable -std-c++0x options with cmake: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x"`, then everything is fine. However, in my library I did not use any c++0x features, so I am reluctant to set std=c++0x option. So I search the head file that defines div_t and find it is defined in stdlib.h within the following MACRO:

```
__BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD


typedef struct
{ 
  int quot;
  int rem;
} div_t;

....
....
__END_NAMESPACE_STD
```

It seems to me that if I can enable these macros I can build the library without enabling c++0x feature. So my question is what I can do in this situation.

By the way, I can build the library very well without enabling c++0x feature if only g++4.4 is installed in the linux machine. When I also install g++4.6 and make g++4.6 the default g++, then the compilation error began to occur. Even I changed the default g++ to g++4.4, the compilation error still exists if I do not enable c++0x feature.

Comment: Perhaps you could disclose what exactly this compilation error is?

Comment: @molbdnilo I added the compilation error as you have suggested.

Comment: `div_t` should be available in C++03. (The macros you found are just used to add things to the `std` namespace when they should be, as far as I know.) Did you `#include <cstdlib>` or `#include <stdlib.h>`?

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks, and if I include <stdlib.h> then the compilation error disappear.

Comment: @molbdnilo I did not realize that I did not include <stdlib.h> because it works when g++4.4 is the only compiler that is installed in the computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macros expand to `namespace std {` and `}` respectively if the code is pulled in through a C++ standard library header. This leads me to believe that you're not #including stdlib.h directly (which is good!).

Earlier versions of libstdc++ pulled symbols from C legacy headers into the global namespace even if the C++ versions of these headers (e.g. `<cstdlib>` instead of `<stdlib.h>`) were used; newer ones place them only in namespace std.

The cleanest way to fix this is to

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

in all translation units where the problem occurs and to use `std::div` instead of `div`. If you're lazy, you can also

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

in all translation units that use `div`, but mixing C and C++ is always icky. Not terribad in this particular case, though.